# Change date format on category axis in my PowerPivot column chart

Tags: excel, charts, number-formatting, powerpivot, date-formatting

I'm trying to show values based on date on a PivotChart (column) in Excel. The problem is that the category label does not seem to follow the number formatting I set. Yes, the underlying table is formatted as date type. I've Googled a bit and the fix that seems to work for most people is to have complete data set (no holes or empty cells). My dataset is complete, so it doesn't help me.

[image]

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

If you want guaranteed consistency of display format, make a display date string in your date dimension that is formatted the way you like. Use this for labels in pivot tables and charts.

You will also have to sort this field by your date field in the model to make sure they display in chronological order.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with data linked from a PowerPivot data model. It is something Microsoft [has been aware of](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/399d66b3-5359-4553-85fa-da1af9934096/formatting-dates-in-excel-powerpivot-tables-and-powerpivot-charts-whose-feature-is-this?forum=sqlkjpowerpivotforexcel) for a long while but unfortunately they haven't implemented the functionality you desire.

There is, however, one work around: you can create a calculated column using `=FORMAT(<date>,"<date format>")`. If you use the formated column instead of your usual date column the axis will be formatted according to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

This is old, but creating a calculated column using =FORMAT(,""),  With this approach you lose the ability to sort the Axis in proper date order.